# How to create dynamic structured documents in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, infopath, formbuilder

I am looking at options to create dynamic web forms within my asp.net application. I know there are lot of open source options available using Jquery, Angular etc.

However the forms I need to create are more of structured documents to capture standard procedures. for e.g. [Patient Registration Form](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/templates/patient-registration-form-TC103974108.aspx)

Though infopath appears to fit in to creation of structured documents, i am not considering since MS has discontinued this product line.

The different options I am exploring are :

- Combine dynamic web form creation using jquery/knockout with a fluid grid library like 
  [Gridster](http://gridster.net/)
- Check if i can publish word forms and capture the user entered data on submit action
- Use Nintex or similar paid product

Any suggestions or directions will be helpful.

Comment: You say dynamic, where does it get the fields from? Will they change over time, session, etc?

Comment: The fields needs to be added by the user/power user creating the form. for e.g http://formoid.com/ or http://www.wufoo.com/form-builder/. They might change over time depending on business changes. But these changes can be treated as different versions for the same form. There wont be any change across sessions

Comment: So you could even generate them using XSD or something. That is what I use for code generation from a database.

Comment: Are suggesting to use XSD/XML to store all the controls required to be rendered on the page? If yes, I would still need to give users/power users options to create the forms like how we create in work templates. wofoo or javascript based approach is fine, but I would still need to manage different layouts like in a page layouts.

Comment: We are saving that info in the database and they are generated on-demand.

Comment: Sorry, Can you clarify which "info" is stored in the database ?

Comment: The layout of the columns, etc. (to give an impression from our corporate website: http://www.invantive.com/products/invantive-producer)